# Cannot access the migration which I have created in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

" PHP artisan make: migration create_poll_table -- create=poll". (I'm using Windows 7)
And I got the file. But cannot migrate using PHP artisan migrate
I have created a migration in laravel 5 using the above command. I got the migration file but when I use PHP migrate, only the first one which is in default (I.e) create_user_table is accessible and I receive a message as table 'users' already exists.

But I wanted to migrate poll file to the database.. is there any other way to solve this.

Comment: Please paste your migration's code and filename.

Comment: I have quoted above. That's the command

Comment: I'm not asking for the command, but for the files that were created after the command. :) In /database/migrations